# Почему возникает ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'exit' (T_EXIT)?

Tags: php

Необходимо получить и отдать картинку пользователю.
Вместо этого, при полностью нормальном коде выдается такая фигня:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'exit' (T_EXIT) in
>   E:\OpenServer\domains\easy\test.php on line 6

Все бы ничего, но вроде никаких запятых не пропустил...

```
$img = 'http://mirgif.com/KARTINKI/kosmos/kosmos-81.jpg';
$headers = get_headers($img,true);
$headers = $headers['Content-Type'];
header("Content-Type: $headers");
$img = file_get_contents($img);  
exit($img);
```

Comment: С виду все ok, но где начало кода, т.е. `<?php`

Comment: Ваш код рабочий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже говорили выше, код рабочий. Возможно ошибка появляется из-за неправильного конца строки. Проверьте , возможно что после `<?php` нет символа конца строки `\n` или он в неправильном формате . Символы конца строки должны быть UNIX Format